# Refresh textbox from binding

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-mobile

I am working on a windows 8.1 app that contains a couple of pages. One page in particular has a text box that is bound to a static resource so that it can be shared between pages. I am able to successfully update that static resource in real-time when I edit the text in the textbox, but I cannot seem to get it to work the other way around. I want to be able to change the string that the binding points to programmatically and have the textbox instantly reflect that.

My static resource is a simple datacontext class that I set up for testing:

```
public class HubDataContext : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string firstNameTextBox;
    public string FirstNameBoxText
    {
        get { return firstNameTextBox; }
        set
        {
            firstNameTextBox = value;
            InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FirstName"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void InvokePropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

To test to see if I am able to do this, I have added a button to the page that modifies the string that the textbox is bound to:

```
((HubDataContext)this.mainHubSection.DataContext).FirstNameBoxText = "TEST!";
```

If I press the button the datacontext's FirstNameBoxText is updated but the text box will not reflect those changes until I navigate to a different page and then navigate back.

I can also modify the text in the textbox itself and then navigate away and come back to show that my changes are reflected. Basically I want to be able to instantly see any changes done to the string that the textbox is bound to without having to navigate away from the page first.

The code for the textbox itself is:

```
 <TextBox x:Name="FirstNameBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="65" Margin="127,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="327" PlaceholderText="" Header="First Name" DataContext="{StaticResource GlobalDataContext}" Text="{Binding FirstNameBoxText, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource GlobalDataContext}}"
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

when you use PropertyChanged event you should use the property name. the binding uses the property name as the key. you will see that after raising the event you can place a breakpoint inside the property setter.

```
public class HubDataContext : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string firstNameTextBox;
    public string FirstNameBoxText
    {
        get { return firstNameTextBox; }
        set
        {
            firstNameTextBox = value;
            InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FirstNameBoxText"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void InvokePropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
    }
}
```